# Is it possible to use dataclass rather than typeddict to define dict typing and make mypy happy?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses, typeddict

I have a dataclass let's say:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: int
    baz: int
```

I have a function that is called from an API receiving json and loading it as a Dict:

```
def handler(foo) -> Foo:
    return Foo(**foo)
```

Is there a way to type foo without having to actually create a `TypedDict` mirror of the dataclass?

Such as:

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict


class SerializedFoo(TypedDict):
    bar: int
    baz: int
```

I find it weird to have to define both.

Comment: You can at least abstract away the construction of the typed dict in a single function. `def make_typed_dict(name, cls): return TypedDict(name, {f.name: f.type for f in dataclasses.fields(cls)})`; SerializedFoo = make_typed_dict('SerializedFoo', Foo)`.

Comment: This illustrates a crucial point: just because the dict's keys and the class's instance attributes have the same name, they are distinct types with distinct uses; at most `dataclasses` could provide `make_typed_dict` as a class method instead of making you define it yourself.

Comment: @chepner it obviously won't work for static type checkers without plugins, and TypedDict is almost useless without it...

Comment: The answer is no. From a typing perspective, the dict `foo` has nothing whatsoever to do with the dataclass `Foo`. The former is a generic container type, the latter is a specific concrete type. As chepner said, the fact that dict keys and attributes match has no bearing on this. And I agree with SUTerliakov that no type checker will interpret this any other way.

Comment: Frame challenge: Would typing `foo` actually improve things? From a typing perspective, calling `handler` is equivalent to calling `Foo` – why not use the latter directly? At some point you *must* tell the type checker that the input is fine and it is much simpler for that point to be `Foo` than some boilerplate.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, I used a dict and once it is loaded in the dataclass, I use the dataclass. No need for a TypedDict if the dataclass is going to validate it nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

In the solution below I've found a way to resolve the problem from the other angle, going from `TypedDict` to `dataclass`. I found that there are many features of TypedDict that are hardcoded into the type checker, and while it may be more appealing the conversion from dataclass to TypedDict seems impossible. However, if we start with a TypedDict, extract the annotations and use these to construct the dataclass, then all behaves as it should. With the help of `dataclass_transform` the type checker is also happy:

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclass
from typing import TypedDict, cast, dataclass_transform

class Test(TypedDict):
    bar: int

@dataclass_transform()
def create_dataclass[T](name: str, cls: type[T]) -> type[T]:
    cls1 = make_dataclass(name, [(k,v) for k,v in cls.__annotations__.items()])
    return cast(type[T],cls1)

test: Test = {'bar': 1}

DataT = create_dataclass('DataT', Test)
print(DataT(
    bar=1
))
```

Note: I am using pyright rather than mypy here, but I think it will amount to the same result

Comment: Can you please clarify what this is supposed to achieve? The function `create_dataclass` is all over the place - it pretends to return a `type[T]` (e.g. *the `TypedDict`* `Test`) but instead returns a separate dataclass type, and due to `@dataclass_transform` it pretends to be an `@dataclass`-like *class to dataclass __decorator__* but is just a regular function. [...]

Comment: [...] Consequently, type-checking of this code fails when doing anything non-trivial - the type-checker is convinced that `DataT(bar=1)["bar"]` is fine (as `DataT` is a `Test` `TypedDict`) which is completely wrong at runtime and should read `DataT(bar=1).bar` (because it is actually a dataclass).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sure, so the `make_dataclass` function does make a dataclass from the `TypedDict`, that at runtime behaves as expected. I was aware that the return type isn't strictly correct, however you're quite right, since the way attributes are accessed is different it means the behaviour of the type doesn't match runtime. I think there might be a way this can be done by using the same class that each is derived from - back to the drawing board!